# Designing iPhone applications that use ASP.NET web methods

Tags: asp.net, iphone, objective-c, web-services

After getting pretty far along with a jQTouch web application for our website, my boss and I decided we may as well just make a true iPhone app instead of struggling with sloppy flickering animations and login authentication issues. We currently have a fully functional web site with some SOAP web services, but we are looking at rewriting these in order to make it easier for the iPhone to call the web methods (for displaying search results, categories, and article) for our app. I have not started anything on the iPhone yet as I am not sure which direction I should be taking.

For a developer that is somewhat unfamiliar with Objective-C (I understand the basics and the syntax), what tools do you recommend to create an iPhone app that uses data from ASP.NET web methods? If everything I need is provided in the iPhone SDK, where do I start?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking to use the SOAP methods from your ASP.NET site, then use Sudzc (http://sudzc.com/).

It will generate a package with all the Objective-C source code and classes written for you, to talk to your SOAP web services.  You can drop it in your iPhone project and you're good to go.

You can tweak the generated code.  Huge time saver :)